# Matplotlib Recursion Depth Limit

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.7

I am building a GUI using Matplotlib. Programmed in it are a lot of different types of key presses that do different things that causes the plot to change and thus needing `plt.show()` or `plt.draw()` to be called (I am not sure of the difference between them). However, at some point too many button presses and `plt.show()`s have been called and I receive the `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` is there a way to avoid this error?

Comment: Without more info, all we can say is, "you recursive function doesn't return soon enough"

Comment: The recursion limit in Python can be changed, but this is almost always a symptom that your code is recursing past the point it should. That is, check the conditions that should have stopped the recursion at a certain point.

Comment: The error message should show you the stack trace. You should be able to see, where your unexpected recursion is happening.